# Register DbContext on services when i using ApplicationDbContextFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

English is not my primary language so I apologize if I make some spelling mistakes here.

I am trying do build a simple asp.net 5.0 application from zero.

Now i'm struggling with de registering process of my appdbcontext class. I'm using a factory that is implementating IDesignTimeDbContextFactory like that:

```
public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>
{
    public AppDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)
             .AddEnvironmentVariables()
             .Build();



        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();

        //var connectionString = configuration
        //            .GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        var connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1; port=3306; database=dbRoomManagement; uid=root; pwd=room123-pw";

        //builder.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString),
        //            x => x.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContextFactory).Assembly.FullName));

        builder.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));



        return new AppDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

When i don't register anything on startp.cs like that:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddServices();
        services.AddRepositories();
        services.AddMappers();




        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "RoomManagement", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "RoomManagement v1"));
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

I get a error saying that was not possible to resolve my AppDbContext:

[image]

If i put the line services.AddDbContext(); to register the AppDbContext i get the message that was mot possible to find the database configurations. I imagine if i use this line the program dont use the factory so they dont find the configurations:

[image]

I'm really cant find something that put me in the right direction here.

Does somebody have something that can help me?

Repository: https://github.com/AndreLuis117/RoomManagement

Comment: I don't think you need a `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`, instead you want a `public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)` and something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0#register-the-schoolcontext

Comment: `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` is used **only** for executing EF Core tools commands like add migration, update database etc. Runtime db context configuration is different, there are a lot of examples how to do that, starting with `AddDbContext(options => options.UseMySql(...))` etc.